# How to make Ruby sleep for amount input by user?

Tags: ruby, sleep

I've tried to make Ruby sleep for an amount that the user has input by doing this:

```
puts "Time?"
time = gets.chomp
time.to_i

sleep(time)
```

Does anyone know what I'm trying to do and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please make sure you read this and try to improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me:

```
puts "Time?"
time = gets.chomp

sleep(time.to_i)
```

`.to_i` doesn't convert the value and overrides the variable, it simply returns the converted result. So it needs to either be used directly in the `sleep` argument or set its own (or another variable):

```
time = time.to_i
sleep(time)
```

Answer (score 4):

Calling `time.to_i` returns an integer, but doesn't change `time` itself. Therefore `time` is still a string.

Change it to:

```
puts 'Time?'
string = gets.chomp
time = string.to_i

sleep(time)
```

Because `to_i` doesn't care if there is a `"\n"` at the end of the string, you can skip the `chomp` call. Therefore you can just write:

```
puts 'Time?'
time = gets.to_i
sleep(time)
```

Comment: I have figured it out. It's a lot like when you add 1 to a variable `a = a+1` except that you're doing `time = time.to_i` which is: `time equals itself to an integer`. Your answer helped me figure this out. Thank you.